# MS Flow turned off, Items added to list, turned flow on, it run for all items

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have created a Flow on SharePoint list, it sends email notification to different users. Now I wanted to add some item in such a way it does not send any notification. I turned off the flow and made the changes to the list by adding new items. But as soon as i turned the flow on it started running for the new items which I added while flow was off.
Kindly suggest, How can I achieve this that flow does not operate when I put it off?

Comment: Would you mind providing details about the flow trigger and any relevant actions to help me better understand the root cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing a while ago and asked the very same question in the Power Community forums. Apparently that behaviour is by design.

If you want to avoid running the flow, the trick is to let the trigger look at a different list, not turn the flow off. You can create a temporary list for that purpose, or use an existing one that you are sure does not get any modifications.

Make the changes to the liste items. When done, point the trigger again to the original list. This time, the flow will not run for all the items that were changed.

I tried it. It works.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.